# If and else if statements. How does it work in my code shown below?

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean-logic

The objective of this code is to output the error message when the age entered is less than 0 or greater than 110. However, if I enter a bizarre number like 600, it doesn't seem to go through the if statement but goes through to the else if statement. 
So I get "I hear you had a birthday and you are 600 years old" instead of "error you are kidding" when age=600. I would like to know how it's being read at the moment and how I can fix it.

```
int main {
    cout << "Enter the age of the recipient";
    cin >> age;

    if ((age <= 0) && (age >= 110))
    {
        cout << "error: you're kidding";
    }

    else if ((age > 0) && (age < 110));
    {
        cout << "I hear you just had a birthday and you are " << age
            << " years old\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Think twice: `if ((age <= 0) && (age >= 110))` can both conditions be true at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had 2 mistakes:

1. in the first if you need to write `||` and not `&&`
2. the second if is not necessary and you need to delete the `;`

   Here is the goood code:

   ```
   int main 
   {
   int age;
   cout << "Enter the age of the recipient";
   cin >> age;

   if ((age <= 0) || (age >= 110))
   {
       cout << "error: you're kidding";
   }

   else 
   {
       cout << "I hear you just had a birthday and you are " << age
           << " years old\n";
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: age is still not defined..:P

Comment: It won't compile… You should check your code before posting it. `main` is a function, not an int.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the `&` operator with the `|` operator.

A number cant be both less than 0 AND greater than 110 at the same time.

You need to check if it's less than 0 OR greater than 110.

so,

`if ((age<0) || (age>110))`

and once you check the first condition you don't need to check the opposite, i.e. if the age is between the two numbers so you can just use an `else` after that.

The reason your getting an output of "I hear you had a birthday and you are 600 years old" is because you have a semicolon at the end of your `else if` statement.

Comment: He's confusing the **`&&` operator** with the **`||` operator**.